# Spring boot post parameter as array getting null value

Tags: java, spring-boot

```
@PostMapping(value=("/addMessage"))
public String addMessagePostPicture(@RequestParam("picture") MultipartFile picture, Map<String, Object> model, HttpServletRequest request, @ModelAttribute MessageForm message) {

String[] contacts = request.getParameterValues("contacts");
    if(message.getContacts() == null){
        System.out.println("yes");
        message.setContact(contacts);
    }


public class MessageForm {
    private String[] contacts;
    public String[] getContacts() {
        return contacts;
    }
    public void setContact(String[] contacts) {
        this.contacts = contacts;
    }
}
```

Why is message.getContacts value null? Request parameter with name contacts excisting.

addMessage.html code part where is getting that contacts parameter value

```
<form id="addMessageForm" class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="addMessage" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group ">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-3 requiredField" for="contacts"> Kontaktid 
            <span class="asteriskField">* </span>
        </label>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addContactModal">Lisa kontakt</button>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <select id="contacts" name="contacts" multiple="multiple">
options added here by javascript
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3">
            <button class="btn btn-primary " name="submit" type="submit" th:text="#{save}"> Salvesta</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

example with javascript generated code

```
<select id="contacts" name="contacts" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="2">test@mail.ee</option>
    <option value="3">mail@mail.ee</option>
    <option value="4">isik@mail.ee</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You must show us the jsp file which submit data to this controller

Comment: In controller you are expected to receive a `@ModelAttribute MessageForm message` but in your jsp form, you did not have any `MessageForm` to submit to your controller, so that cause your error

Comment: https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/ i done like here sent MessageForm from controller to view and used there th:object and th:field but still null.